# multipart/mixed: with axios and reactjs for several json requests

Tags: reactjs, axios, youtube-data-api

I am trying to request multiple JSON requests for youtube api v3: The aim is to get the latest 25 videos uploaded from 5 different channels.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANL000}&channelType=any&maxResults=25&order=date&key={XXXXX}
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANL001}&channelType=any&maxResults=25&order=date&key={XXXXX}
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANL002}&channelType=any&maxResults=25&order=date&key={XXXXX}
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANL003}&channelType=any&maxResults=25&order=date&key={XXXXX}
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANL004}&channelType=any&maxResults=25&order=date&key={XXXXX}
```

Now i want to send a multipart/mixed request to "www.googleapis.com" requesting JSON for all the above api links.

How to do this with axios in reactJS.

Also ref: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch#example

the following is my axios code:

```
  axios.get('www.googleapis.com/batch')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

where should i include the list of urls in the above axios code

Comment: I usually do this in a redux action but there's nothing stopping you from creating a function that calls `axios` to make the request and return it as a promise, so you can get all 5 calls...

Comment: I dont know the syntax how to write it. Can you show how to write this in axios. I can then manage the output in reactjs